# Can I link the "Program Files (x86)\Common Files" folder to a different physical drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm trying to save some space on my SSD, and I was wondering if I `mklink /j` that folder if there would be any consequences?

Comment: Yes; There will be consequences.  If you are going to move a folder within Program Files move the entire directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage will definitely vary here.  Windows has supported "Reparse Points" since Windows 2000 in the form of Directory Junctions.  As of Vista/Server 2008, NTFS now officially supports Symbolic Links.  However, the feature has never been widely used because they just don't work the way they do in *nix operating systems.  If you symlink C:\Program Files\Common Files to D:\wherever, it will likely break some apps.  So proceed with caution.

As the old joke goes, "Microsoft doesn't know how to spell the word SYMLIN~1.lnk"